# expected payoff of $2^n$ ? How to understand?

Tags: probability

Ken flips a fair coin until he observes a head. He receives the minimum of $ 64 $ and $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of times that Ken flips the coin. What is his expected payoff?

My attempt:
$E(x) = 64 + \frac{1}{2}(2^n + E(x))$
$E(x) = 128 + (2^n)$

But I am not sure how to interpret this?

Can I use geometric distribution to model this?

Comment: Of course the expected value is bounded, the payouts themselves are bounded.  Just list the possible payouts and compute their probabilities.

Comment: @lulu hi lulu thanks. Like list n =1 and so on?

Comment: Yes.  There are very few possible outcomes, just list them all and compute their probabilities.

Comment: @lulu What do you mean by very few possible outcomes? I thought n can be anything up to a very large number?

Comment: But your payout can't be.  Start by listing all the possible payouts.  Note that once $n$ is big enough, there's no point tossing the coin any further...the payout can't change.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to writing out each possibility. You can use conditional expectation. Let $X = \min(2^n,64)$ with $n = 1, 2, \dots$. Then
\begin{align}
E(X) & = E(X | n \le 5) P(n \le 5) + E(X| n > 5) P(n >5) \\
& = E(2^n | n \le 5) P(n \le 5) + 64 P(n>5).
\end{align}
Can you finish from there?

Comment: Hi Greg thanks for the help, but I have no idea what you have just done. Like why min(2^n, 64)? and where did the 5 comes from? I have never seen a conditional expression before.

Comment: If you have not done conditional probability/expectation, then you can disregard my hint. See @lulu comments in your OP, for doing it by hand.

Comment: To address your other question though, $n \le 5$ is because that is the last number where $2^n < 64$ and so it serves as a natural partition for calculating $E(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Head wins 2. Tails, heads wins 4. TTH wins 8, TTTH wins 16, TTTTH wins 32, five or more tails wins 64.

Easy to add the expected value.

Something with either your question or interpretation is badly wrong.